# Wordpress Not Displaying Tables Correctly?

Tags: php, wordpress, html-table

I am using a post template from within Wordpress to create a table. However the formatting is a bit messed up.

The PHP that generates the code goes in and queries a server for the user's test information for the day. It then trims down that internal report to get just the table. Note that the report does not close the `</tbody>` tag, so I had to use a str_replace to close that tag.

```
global $current_user;

get_currentuserinfo();

$raw_contents = file_get_contents('http://******/NamedRptRun.asp?Rpt=DailyUserSum&Prj=******_****UserId='.($current_user->user_login));

    $trim_raw = trim($raw_contents);
//echo htmlentities($trim_raw);

if ($trim_raw == 'No Records Returned')  {

    echo 'No test cases to report today.';

} else {

    $tag = '<TABLE';

    $topTrim_contents = stristr($raw_contents, $tag);

    $tag = '</BODY>';

    $table_only = stristr($topTrim_contents, $tag, TRUE);

    $table_only = str_replace("</tr></table>", "</tbody></tr></table>",$table_only);

   echo htmlentities($table_only);
   echo str_replace(array("\r\n","\n","\t"), ' ',$table_only);

}
```

This provides me with both code for the table (only for debugging purposes), as well as what should be the table. However, the values of the table are not actually within the table, but are shown on the line above the table.

```
<TABLE cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 border=1 bordercolor=Silver>
<thead class=b>
<TR bgColor=WHITE>
<th>&nbsp;Engineer&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;Passed&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;PWWarn&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;Blocked&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;Failed&nbsp;</th><th>&nbsp;Total Run&nbsp;</th></tr></thead><tbody class=h><TR bgColor=#F1F1F1><TD nowrap>myname</td><TD nowrap>1</td><TD nowrap>0</td><TD nowrap>0</td><TD >0</td><TD nowrap>1</td></tbody></tr></table>

10001
 Engineer    Passed      PWWarn      Blocked     Failed      Total Run 
myname
```

Anyone have any suggestions as to why this might happen?

Pasting View-Page Source of the final table that was generated.

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <thead class="b">
        <tr bgcolor="WHITE">
            <th> Engineer</th>
            <th> Passed</th>
            <th> PWWarn</th>
            <th> Blocked</th>
            <th> Failed</th>
            <th> Total Run</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="h">
        <tr bgcolor="#F1F1F1">
            <td nowrap="nowrap">myname</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Your closing `</tbody>` and `</tr>` tags are the wrong way round, for starters. Also, which browser are you using? Might help me reproduce the problem...

Comment: I'm using latest version of firefox and Chrome. I'm also running Wordpress 3.2.1, and funny thing is, it works fine in 3.1.

Comment: Well, your HTML -- even your original version; I just pasted it in -- renders okay in a post in WordPress 3.2.1 for me. Maybe your theme CSS or a plugin or something else is mangling things?

Comment: Yeah I tried that as well, I'm going to go through and disable everything that isn't necessary. Could it be SimplePostTemplate or Exec-PHP plugins? The process to get from the results server to the post relies on both of these plugins.

Comment: What does the actual, rendered HTML look like once you've generated it? As in, use "View->Page Source"? That'll eliminate a lot of things that could be causing the problem.

Comment: That makes things even more interesting. I have posted the View-Page Source excerpt in the question above.

Comment: @SakamotoKazuma let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2742/discussion-between-matt-gibson-and-sakamoto-kazuma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found after contacting the author of SimplePostTemplate. It seems as if wordpress will filter out bad HTML, which is exactly what it did with my table, and thus why it didn't show properly.

I was able to ask the other department to clean up their html before it got to wordpress, and thus passing the filters and solving the issue.